# Resizing UITextView's WIDTH based on content

Tags: ios, uitextview, contentsize

I am trying to resize a UITextView based on content. I would like to resize the height if it is multiline but when the text is really short I would like to resize the width to the content as well. Currently the height works but the width doesn't. I have tried

```
UITextView *view = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 130)];
view.text = @"This is a test";
CGSize size = [view.text sizeWithFont:view.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, size.width,size.height);
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

which is the closest I have come. But this doesn't resize the height and is chopping off the last word in the text ('test'). To resize the height I have tried both:

```
CGSize size = [view sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT)];
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, size.width,size.height);
```

and

```
[view sizeToFit];
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

which both work for height but don't seem to resize width (I don't know why they wouldn't work for width..)

Comment: it's not resizing the width because you have hardcoded the width to be 300 with `[view sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT)]`

Comment: What about using a temp `UILabel` (with frame 0,0,0,0), and using `sizeToFit` to it using this size for your `UITextView`

Comment: I was under the impression that the 300 was the max width that it would assign. Is that not true?

Comment: Indeed, but if your text is "too small", it won't... You could check before if the `width` returned is less than 300 or not taking it in account or not.

Comment: @Larme, your solution in the first comment has the same problem of cutting off the last word. 
I don't understand what you are suggesting in your second comment.